# Length of string not considering zeros in the start

Tags: java

I am trying the following question. I need to find the length of integer digit so I converted it into string and I am able to get output for all the numbers except the numbers starting with zeros. I am only able pass 1 testcase out of three. I am not able to figure out what else is wrong in my code.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {

public static void main(String []args) {
    int no;
    int sum;

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    no = sc.nextInt();

    String x=Integer.toString(no);

    int len=x.length();

    int lno=no%10;   //3rd digit
    int fno=no;      //first digit
    int mno=(no/10)%10;   //middle digit

    while(fno>=10) {
        fno/=10;    
    }

    sum=fno+lno;

    if(len!=3) {
        System.out.print("Invalid Input\n");

    } else {
        if(sum==mno) {
            System.out.print("Lucky Number\n");

        } else {
            System.out.print("Not A Lucky Number\n");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: maybe you can reformat your code snippet to make it more readable

Comment: What error are you facing? Also please do edit the question for better readability and understanding.

Comment: I don’t think I understand your question. What should be the output if the input is 022? 0242? I believe `sc.nextInt()` will never tell you if there were leading zeroes, so you may want to look for another input method.

Comment: Java has general Naming-Conventions. Reading, understand and applying them won't hurt you & it'll certainly increase the readability of your code. :)

Comment: Please don't downvote the question because of stuff like poor code formatting. People don't ask questions because they already know everything...

Comment: I dont know what is exactly wrong with the code. I get correct outputs for the input according to the question except the one leading with zeros.  I am not able to pass the test cases.

Comment: If Java `String`s ended with a `null`, `len` should be 4, not 2 (otherwise that would mean your input would only contain one useful character and `null`). But it's not the case, they are not null terminated, so you should check if `len != 3`.

Comment: I did with len !=3 but I cannot pass the test case

Comment: The leading zero survive the integer convertion ? I doubt it...

Comment: What is your test case? 165?

Comment: I dont know the test cases. It has 3 of which the above code passes only 1.

Comment: is `000` a lucky number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the `next(Pattern)` method available in `Scanner`?

You can then use a regex to match a 3-digit number and if it doesn't match it will throw a `InputMismatchException` which you can catch and output *Invalid Input*.

If it does match then you know you have a `String` of length 3 which you can then use each char as an individual number. Add the first and last index together and see if it equals the second index.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {

        try {
            String number = scan.next(Pattern.compile("\\d{3}"));

            int i = Integer.parseInt("" + number.charAt(0));
            int j = Integer.parseInt("" + number.charAt(1));
            int k = Integer.parseInt("" + number.charAt(2));

            if ((i + k) == j) {
                System.out.println("Lucky Number");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not A Lucky Number");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming leading zeros must be part of the input you should not convert to int at all. Just parse the String to extract the digits.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = sc.nextLine():

if (input.length() != 3) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input");
}

int first = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, 1));
int second = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(1, 2));
int third = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2, 3));

if (first + third != second) {
    System.out.print("Not a ");
}
System.out.println("Lucky Number");
```

Comment: Much more interresting to work with numbers, especially if you only have integers.

Comment: Of course Math.log10 works! It just doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about that problem is to get digits using string indexing. This approach would be helpful when the definition of lucky number changes to something like sum of 1st and 8th digit.

Here is a sample:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String no=sc.nextLine();

        if(no.matches("^[0-9]+$"))
        {
            if(no.length()!=3)
                System.out.println("Not a Valid Input");
            else if(no.length()==3 && (Character.getNumericValue(no.charAt(0))+Character.getNumericValue(no.charAt(2)))==Character.getNumericValue(no.charAt(1)))
                System.out.println("Lucky Number");
            else
                System.out.println("Not A Lucky Number");
        }else
            System.out.println("Not a number");
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
$ javac Test.java 
$ java Test
165
Lucky Number
$ java Test
022
Lucky Number
$ java Test
145
Not A Lucky Number
$ java Test
12
Not a Valid Input
```

Comment: Your code will never output "Not a Valid Input". And lucky numbers starting with a zero will fail, like in OP's code.

Comment: One last remaining quibble, your code will not print anything if the input is not a number.

Comment: @Valentin fixed it